# How to compare rows with Talend Integration?

Tags: talend

I want to compare two data source using Talend Integration. The first is an xls metadata and the other is a DB table. I need to compare all rows of the files. I trying to use tMap component but doesn't work for me yet.

How to make for compare this rows?

Bellow is an image of my flow.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Have you a field (ideally a key) to perform your comparison? Or would you like just use the rows input order for each source?

Comment: I don't have the Id for two souces, only souce has Id.
I would like compare only the string of sources.

For example:

Source 1:
USA
CANADA


Source 2:
USA
CANADA
BRAZIL

In this case, I need get only BRAZIL, because is different between the files. Did you understand?

I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: No problem for your English. Mine is not perfect too :) If I understand, you would like to compare all rows of the two sources? And then catch the rows which match (or not)?

Comment: I need catch the rows dismatch.

Comment: You can follow the Corentin's answer :) In addition, you can also perform some cleaning before to match your fields in your tMap (downcase, trim, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a screenshot of your tMap_2 Component.

If you have a 'country' field in both sources for example, you can put an inner join between those two fields in your tMap, and catch the 'inner join reject' in the output. This way you'll get an output with all rows that are in source 1 but not in source 2.

[image]

Comment: I came right into this part, but I need the output of source 2 reject join. How to make this?

Comment: Reverse your Main (row3) and your Lookup (row4). Data from your file is your main flow, data from your database is your lookup, and catch inner join rejected lines (i.e. data which are your file but not in your database table).